# Splitting list into smaller lists of equal values

Tags: python

I am looking to transform a list into smaller lists of equal values. An example I have is:

```
["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
```

to

```
[["a", "a", "a"], ["b", "b"], ["c", "c", "c", "c"]]
```

What do you think is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are equal values necessarily consecutive?

Comment: I sorted the list to make values consecutive

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to solve the problem:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [list(grp) for k, grp in groupby(["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"])]
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']]
```

It only groups consecutive equal elements but that seems enough in your case.

Comment: One can (should?) sort the list before grouping.

Comment: That depends on the exact requirements. If it should group equal consecutive elements then "no", if it should group all equal values (overall) and keep the order then there are better ways using an `OrderedDict` and `Counter`. Just in case the order doesn't matter and equal elements aren't consecutive then sorting is an efficient strategy. The most efficient way for the example given is just using `groupby` (without sorting). :)

Comment: Agree. The OP just said that they sorted the list for convenience.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `collections.Counter`

```
>>> lst = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(lst).most_common()
[('c', 4), ('a', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

This works even when the values are not ordered and provides a very compact representation which then you could expand if needed into lists:

```
>>> [[i]*n for i,n in collections.Counter(lst).most_common()]
[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]
```

Comment: Do you know how to access the counter value of each of the elements? In this case the 4, 3 , and 2

Comment: Sure, just use: `[n for i,n in collections.Counter(lst).most_common()]`

Answer (score 2):

Another manner to have your desired output is by using `defaultdict` from `collections` module (best time using this approach was: ~= 0.02s same as using `groupby`):

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"]
b = defaultdict(list)
for k in a:
    b[k].append(k)

>>> b 
defaultdict(list,
            {'a': ['a', 'a', 'a'], 'b': ['b', 'b'], 'c': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']})
```

So, what you have to do now is:

```
list(b.values())
>>> [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'd personally go with `itertools.groupby` as the most convinient way, you've asked for efficiency and this should be considerably faster than any of the `itertools` options:

```
data = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"] 

lookup = {}  # lookup map
result = []
for element in data:
    if element not in lookup:
        target = lookup[element] = [element]
        result.append(target)
    else:
        lookup[element].append(element)

print(result)
# [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c']]
```

If the data is always ordered (i.e. elements don't mix) this can be further optimized without a lookup table and using a list comprehension for maximum performance.

**UPDATE** - Some clarification on efficiency and operation. If you set up your test as:

```
from itertools import groupby

def itools_func(data):
    return [list(grp) for k, grp in groupby(data)]

def manual_func(data):
    lookup = {}
    result = []
    for element in data:
        if element not in lookup:
            target = lookup[element] = [element]
            result.append(target)
        else:
            lookup[element].append(element)
    return result
```

The problem is that those two will not return the same values:

```
test_data = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "b", "a"]

itools_func(test_data)  # [['a', 'a'], ['b'], ['c', 'c'], ['b'], ['a']]
manual_func(test_data)  # [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c']]
```

From OP's question, I understood he wants the latter one (based on his comment "I sorted the list to make values consecutive") because with a sorted list this can be done far easier. So, if we feed those functions a really long list:

```
test_data = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c"] * 10000  # 10000 x the original
```

On my system it clocks as follows:

```
itools_func - 100 loops: 2.668s, per loop: 26.68ms
manual_func - 100 loops: 1.005s, per loop: 10.05ms
```

But, this is an unfavorable setting for `itertools.groopby`. If the data was to be sorted like:

```
test_data = ["a"] * 3000 + ["b"] * 2000 + ["c"] * 40000
```

The story is quite a bit different as the C backend kicks in:

```
itools_func - 1000 loops: 656.3ms, per loop: 656.3µs
manual_func - 1000 loops: 4.816s, per loop: 4.816ms
```

When the data is sorted the manual function can be further optimized but it will hardly beat what `itertools` does under the hood.

Comment: Well, if you care about efficiency you should probably use a `defaultdict`, or at least use the `.setdefault` method of plain `dict`s, instead of checking `if element not in lookup:`. Also, I'm curious why you say this will be considerably faster. Do you have a timing? `itertools.groupby` is written in C, after all.

Comment: That's only "more" efficient for really short inputs. If the `data` is big or huge this will be much slower.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @MSeifert - I've updated my post with some numbers. As for why not using `defaultdict` - it doesn't add anything here, in fact it would just add more steps when extracting the data as one would need to keep a separate list, together with the `if element in lookup`, to maintain the order. I tried it with `defaultdict` and it ends up ~1% slower on average.